# The version of CKEditor could not be detected

Tags: wysiwyg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CKEDITOR not working Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28716/ckeditor-not-working-drupal-7)

When I try to enable CkEditor, I get the following error.

[image: screenshot]

I have already extracted the files in sites/all/libraries/ckeditor.

Is there any problem with the version of this module? How can I fix this?

I have already read [Ckeditor doesn't work](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28716/ckeditor-not-working-drupal-7).

Comment: Theres a ckeditor folder within another ckeditor, this can catch people out...

Comment: Simply make sure the `ckeditor.js` is accessible with the given `URL`. Make sure you read the `Readme.txt`

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate. There are other reasons why ckeditor could not be detected. V4 of CKEditor has changed to use double quote marks instead of singles, which causes it to be undetected by WYSIWYG.

Comment: I was having the same problem. I made the change as suggested at https://drupal.org/comment/6814058#comment-6814058 and it worked fine for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do after installing the module is go to http://ckeditor.com and download the latest version. Then uncompress the contents of the 'ckeditor' directory of the downloaded file to this folder 'libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor'.

**Installation steps**

1. Unzip the module files to the "sites/all/libraries" directory. It should now
     contain a "ckeditor" directory.
2. Download standalone CKEditor from http://ckeditor.com/download. Unzip the
     contents of the "ckeditor" directory from the installation package to the
     "sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor" directory.
     Note: you can skip uploading the "_samples" and "_source" folders.
3. Enable the module in the "Administration panel > Modules > User Interface" section.
4. Grant permissions for using CKEditor in the
     "Administration panel > People > Permissions" section.
     Note: In order to enable the file browser, refer to the
           "Installing CKFinder" section.
5. Adjust CKEditor profiles in the
     "Administration panel > Configuration > Content Authoring > CKEditor" section.
     Profiles determine which options are available to users based on the input format system.

Comment: So there should be a second hierarchy of ckeditor is needed right ?

Comment: @Nikhil if you follow the steps exactly, it hink you will get it work.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get CKEditor 4 working having downloaded it and used it on a clean install so follow the upgrade advice above.

Read the instructions in the WYSIWYG config as to the path, it should be:

```
sites\all\libraries\ckeditor
```

Note: the if you extract to this folder you will get

```
sites\all\libraries\ckeditor\ckeditor
```

which obviously won't work as the ckeditor.js file is in the wrong place!