# Creating and Linking anchors using CKEditor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor in my drupal 7 website. I am designed a new content type, in which I am writing about project activities in the following manner.

```
(1) Project A [anchor]
     This project describes about the design and analysis of Binary Search Tree
(2) Project B [anchor]
     This project describes about the design and analysis of Red Back Tree
```

Now, from a different page, I want to provide a link to anchors in following way-

```
The Binary Search Tree [as described here] also called an ordered or sorted binary tree.
```

I wanted to know using CKEditor-

1. How to create links (anchors) inside a page?
2. How to add these links to text on a new page?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CKEditor, not Drupal.

Comment: @Letharion: The question is already answered. See below before posting

Comment: Yet, it is not a Drupal-related question since CKEditor can be used without Drupal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to create links (anchors) inside a page?

There is an icon with a flag. You click on it and you create the anchor.

[image: Anchor icon]

If the icon is missing, go to /admin/config/content/ckeditor , edit the respecive profile and customize the icons under section 'Editor appearance'.

> How to add these links to text on a new page?

You add a link as you would:

[image]

Comment: Based on your answer I can add the anchors but I am still unable to link anchor to text. The website URL is http://127.0.0.1/drupal I notieced that after linking this anchor in another page, the URL becomes http://127.0.0.1/projects/#project_a  (I don't want to declare the complete website URL) . Please see the screenshot [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51884474/img_1.PNG)

Comment: The picture shows that you have specified as link: `/projects/#project_a`, so this will drive you to `127.0.0.1/projects/#project_a` if the site is deployed on `127.0.0.1`. If you want it to go to `127.0.0.1/drupal/another_page#my_anchor` then you have to specify `/drupal/another_page#my_anchor`. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2005174/940098). This is an HTML-related comment btw, not CKEditor/Drupal.

Comment: Thank you for the info. As I said earlier, I don't wanna enter absolute URL. Is it possible to work with relative URL? (Since my website is going to be deployed in live server. At that time I can't afford to change all these URLs)

Comment: So I assume that your issue is that you have installed Drupal in a subdirectory in your development server. You can deal with this in many ways, but what I do and I recommend is to create a virtual host at your development server and move Drupal to the document root.

Comment: No. Currently the document root is drupal, which is going to be changed. It will be web.example.com/~ravi . That is why I wanted to work with relative URL. Alternatively does there exist any variable, which can tell me the current document root? In that case i can link the anchor by writing $DocumentRoot/projects/#project_a

Comment: What Wtower has described above is how you would make a relative path work. If it's not working for you; You might want to look into updating ckeditor.

Comment: Also make sure the select list next to the URL is set to Other.

Comment: @Wtower and @FatGuyLaughing: I was selecting `http` as protocol and the scnreenshot attached above is in `Greek`. By using Google translator, I got to know that protocol is other i.e. άλλα . I updated the CKEditor (faced some issue, solved by referring [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/70944/26927)). Thank you for the help.